# Using ELMAH To Send A Daily Digest Email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, error-handling, elmah

I've searched online to see if ELMAH can send daily emails and from the reading I've done, the developers say to use the RSS feed instead of emails. [See this post for details](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/issues/detail?id=14). My company wants a daily email sent using ELMAH. Does anyone know if this is possible or of any workarounds for sending daily emails with ELMAH?

Comment: Feedburner offers a daily email summary subscription of an RSS feed (though I'm not sure if it limits how many items it shows). But, it would mean your RSS feed would have to be publicly accessible somewhere, which may not  work for you, or be a good idea to have your error log RSS publicly available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where do your log your errors to? Database/ File / RAM? I would imagine that, for all of the back-end storages supported by ELMAH, except RAM, you could easily write a console app to send this daily email summary that you want.

For what is worth, look at the [System.Net.Mail.MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx) and [System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) classes on MSDN.

Comment: We're keeping it in the database. This sounds like the way to go. I was hoping ELMAH had a built-in solution, but this will work for our purposes.